# Putnam and Beyond 2e Section 1.5 Example

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

Question, from Putnam and Beyond, 2E, Section 1.5, first example: There are $n$ markers, each with one side white and the other side black, aligned in a row with their white sides up. At each step, if possible, we choose a marker with the white side up (but not one of the outermost markers), remove it, and reverse the two neighboring markers. Prove that one can reach a configuration with only two markers left if and only if $n-1$ is not divisible by 3.

I claim this example has a counterexample, namely n=6.
My approach is a combinatoric approach: we can count all the valid approaches and show that we don't have any.

Start with our starting arrangement $$WWWWWW$$.
We cannot choose either of the $W$s in the middle because if we do, we would be unable to remove either the second, or the 5th tile. So we must start with tile 2 or tile 5.
$$BOBWWW $$.

We still may not remove tile 4 otherwise we will be unable to remove tile 5. So we remove tile 5. $$BOBBOB$$

And we complete, with 4 remaining tiles. $\square$

Please tell me if there is something wrong with my solution. If not then is this a glaring error or omission (say the condition $n>6$ or something)?

I think the only ambiguity I that potentially could be is if we didn't want to count the outermost markers. If that's the case, this is a poorly worded example.

Comment: Perhaps the intention was that after removing a marker, the two halves of the row should be pushed together, leaving no gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the removed markers leave no actual, empty spots behind. Or, equivalently, "reverse the two neighbouring markers" looks past these open spots to the next remaining marker. Otherwise, *specifying* that there are *two* of them seems a bit strange.

We have the following sequence of moves:
$$\begin{array}{llllll}
W&W&W&W&W&W\\
W&W&B&O&B&W\\
B&O&W&O&B&W\\
W&O&O&O&W&W\\
B&O&O&O&O&B\end{array}
$$
where $W$ is a marker with the whie side up, $B$ is a marker with the black side up, and $O$ is a removed marker.

Comment: I believe this is the most likely scenario! Thank you!